# How to express Hotelling T² test as a Likelihood ratio between two multivariate linear models?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model

Is it possible, given that Hotelling's T² (or Hotelling-Lawley Trace for that matter) is just a generalization of Student's T, to reformulate the same testing procedure (to test if two vectors differ) as a relative Likelihood comparison between two multivariate linear models?

Analogous to expressing a t-test as a linear model (in Wilkinson Notation) `value ~ 1 + group` and then comparing it to the intercept-only model?

Answer (score 2):

When Hotelling's $T^2$ test is called a likelihood-ratio test, that doesn't mean that $T^2$ is itself a likelihood ratio, but rather that the test based on $T^2$ is the same as the test based on the likelihood ratio, because $T^2$ is a monotone function of a likelihood ratio. A likelihood ratio test rejects the null hypothesis precisely if the likelihood ratio is too extreme (meaning too large or too small, depending on which quantity you decided to put in the numerator and which in the denominator). The likelihood ratio is too extreme precisely if $T^2$ is too big, so although $T^2$ is not itself the likelihood ratio, the test based on it is the same test as the one based on the likelihood ratio; thus it is a likelihood-ratio test.

You have $X\sim\operatorname N(\mu,\Sigma),$ where $\mu\in\mathbb R^p$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}.$ The null hypothesis says $\mu=\mu_0.$ The likelihood function based on an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ is
\begin{align}
& L(\mu,\Sigma) \\[8pt]
\propto {} & \prod_{i=1}^n \left( (\det \Sigma)^{-p/2} \exp\left( -\frac12 (x_i-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1} (x_i-\mu) \right) \right) \\
& \text{where “$\propto$” means proportional as a function} \\ & \text{of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$} \\[8pt]
= {} & (\det\Sigma)^{-np/2} \exp \left( -\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1} (x_i-\mu) \right).
\end{align}
It is well known (and here I omit the proof) that the value of $(\mu,\Sigma)$ that maximizes this is
\begin{align}
\mu = {} & \text{the sample mean} = \overline x = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\[8pt]
\Sigma = {} & \text{the sample covariance matrix} \\
& S = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)(x_i-\overline x)^\top, \\
& \text{(which is a biased estimator of} \\
& \text{the population covariance matrix).}
\end{align}

That, however, is under the alternative hypothesis. Under the null hypothesis, one has $\mu = \mu_0.$

The likelihood ratio is therefore
\begin{align}
& \frac{(\det S)^{-np/2} \exp \left( -\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\overline x) \right)}{(\det S)^{-np/2} \exp \left( -\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\mu_0) \right)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \exp\left( \frac12\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\mu_0) - (x_i-\overline x)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\overline x) \right) \right)
\end{align}
and one rejects the null hypothesis if this is too big. It is too big precisely if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\mu_0) - (x_i-\overline x)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\overline x) \tag 1
$$
is too big.

Now we use some algebra to massage a portion of the expression above.
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (x_i-\mu_0) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=1}^n \big((x_i- \overline x) + (\overline x - \mu_0)\big)^\top S^{-1} \big((x_i- \overline x) + (\overline x - \mu_0)\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- \overline x)^\top S^{-1} (x_i- \overline x) \tag2 \\
& + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- \overline x)^\top S^{-1} (\overline x - \mu_0) \tag3 \\
& + \sum_{i=1}^n (\overline x - \mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (x_i- \overline x) \tag4 \\
& + \sum_{i=1}^n (\overline x - \mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (\overline x - \mu_0). \tag5
\end{align}
Observe that line $(3)$ above adds up to $0$ because as $i$ goes from $1$ up to $n,$ $S^{-1} (\overline x - \mu_0)$ does not change, and may therefore be pulled out of the sum, getting
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- \overline x) \right)^\top S^{-1} (\overline x - \mu_0)
$$
and the expression within the big parentheses is $0.$ Similarly, line $(4)$ is $0.$

So the expression on line $(1)$ adds up to
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i=1}^n (\overline x - \mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (\overline x - \mu_0) \\[8pt]
= {} & n (\overline x - \mu_0)^\top S^{-1} (\overline x - \mu_0),
\end{align}
and that is ($n$ times) Hotelling's $T^2.$

Thus the likelihood ratio is too big precisely when Hotteling's $T^2$ is too big.

(How big is too big? That depends on the level of the test and on the probability distribution that $T^2$ has when the null hypothesis is true.)